# html-react-parser: Replace DOM Node with another DOM Node containing inner text child (A-link)

Tags: reactjs, html-react-parser

Using `html-react-parser`, I need to output my string as JSX, but with the replacement of all
`<a href=...`> to the encapsulating new element `<LinkContainer to={href}><a>..</a></LinkContainer>` which will contain the `<a>`. In other words, I'm wrapping my A-links in a LinkContainer tag.

The problem is, I don't know how to express the Inner Text of the A-tag I'm replacing, which has to be included:

```
parse(successMessage, { 
        replace: domNode => {
            if (domNode.attribs && domNode.attribs.href) {
                return <LinkContainer to={domNode.attribs.href}><a href="#">How to get the Inner Text?</a></LinkContainer>;
            }  
        }}
    );
```

Nothing like `innerText` or `text` is available. The DOM Nodes that come to me are

- The A-tag itself
- Its child, which is inner text, a separate node

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found the solution. You can just replace the A-tag and get the link's text from `domNode.children[0].data`.

```
    parse(successMessage, { 
            replace: domNode => {
                if (domNode.attribs && domNode.attribs.href) {
                    return <LinkContainer to={domNode.attribs.href}><a href="#">{domNode.children[0].data}</a></LinkContainer>;
                }  
            }}
        )
```